# Returning values from multiple options in Regex

Tags: regex

I am searching for specific terms in a block of text only when they are surrounded by other 'qualifying' terms.  I have made a regex where each of those qualifying terms is an option:

```
(?<QUALIFY_A>(A\s(?<TERM>(Hi|Bye)))|(?<QUALIFY_B>B\s(?<TERM1>(Hi|Bye)))|(?<QUALIFY_C>C\s(?<TERM2>(Hi|Bye))))
```

http://regex101.com/r/xR0uA9

So far this behaves as I expect as it finds the first match of the term when preceded by the qualifying expression. However Ideally I'd like to get each one returned, in other words not have the regex quit once matched. I realize if I just had one option I could do /1/2 to get multiple matches to the one option but in this case trying to get multiple matches to different options.

Comment: What language are you using? In PHP you need to use `preg_match_all`, in other languages you need to use the `global` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

try putting `g` in the modifier box you can see on the right hand side of the regex

Comment: +1 for a beautiful all-lowercase answer. :) isn't that `g` an endearing quirk of regex101 by the way? since it's not a universal regex modifier, to php heads it might feel like an easter egg.